# raising token variable inside double for loop

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, cmd

So I have this piece of code which is basically just a prototype, but I can't get it to work because tokens parameter of for loop doesn't like variables defined in a `!var!` way which can be used with delayed expansion.

```
@echo on
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set string=4 1 5 1 6 1 6 2
set b=1
set c=2
for /L %%o in (1, 2, 8) do (
  call set /a "b=%%o"
  call set /a "c=%%o + 1"
  FOR /F "tokens=%b%,%c%" %%G IN ("%string%") DO @echo %%G %%H
)
```

The result that I am getting is:

```
4 1
4 1
4 1
4 1
```

And the result I want is:

```
4 1
5 1
6 1
6 1
```

I have been experimenting for a while how to fix this issue but couldn't find a solution anyways. Is there any simple way to fix this or do I have to try and make it with single loop and maybe some goto's or call functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call out to a function.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set string=4 1 5 1 6 1 6 2
set b=1
set c=2
for /L %%o in (1, 2, 8) do (
  set /a "b=%%o"
  set /a "c=%%o + 1"
  CALL :label1 !b! !c!
)
PAUSE
GOTO :EOF


:label1
FOR /F "tokens=%1,%2" %%G IN ("%string%") DO @echo %%G %%H
GOTO :EOF
```